# How To Change A Cell Value Based On Option In A Data Validation Drop Down List From Another Cell In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets, in one sheet labeled "Main" I have a quote form I have created to send our clients price estimates. Within that form at the bottom is a sales tax - being that our company sells in different city's, we have different tax rates for each city.

So, I created a Data Validation drop down list to choose from the various city's, which all the data is in on the sheet 2 labeled "Tax Rates".

In the "Tax Rates" sheet I have column A1 labeled "Tax Name" and column B1 labeled "Tax Rate". Underneath "Tax Name" are all the city's names. Under "Tax Rate" are all the sales tax percentages to correspond with each city in column A.

I would like the cell next to the drop down list on the quote form on "Main" to change to the corresponding Tax Rate when a city is selected from that drop down list.

For example:

If I select "City of San Fransisco" from the drop down list, I would like the cell next to it to change to that specific tax rate percentage.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the desired sheet by utilize'vlookup' only. To do so, in your tax rate sheet, you will list down all the city together with the tax rate, then use 'data validation' to obtain the city name, and `vlookup` to show the tax rate. I do the calculation within same sheet for easier explantion, fyi.

```
=vlookup(A2,Tax!A:B,2,false)
```

**Dropdown list**
[image]

**Final result**

[image]

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on how to accomplish this between 2 different sheets?

Comment: You can just vlookup the second sheet only, see my edited answer...